# sql server delete many transaction taking to much time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have housekeeping stored procedure. 
I have a problem when i execute a query for housekeeping. It took longer hour to finish the script for 35000 rows. 
Is it because of sql server performance ? Because when i run in localhost where there are less memory use it execute smoothly and finish around 1 hour.
I am using delete. Below is example of my housekeeping script.
-- Build SQL Statement - Start

```
SET @SQLStatement = 'DELETE FROM dbo.tPgt_ReviewedFile WHERE [File_Id] = '
    + LTRIM(STR(@FileId))
SET @SQLStatement = @SQLStatement
    + '; DELETE FROM dbo.tPgt_WorkFlow WHERE [File_Id] = ' + LTRIM(STR(@FileId))
SET @SQLStatement = @SQLStatement
    + '; DELETE FROM dbo.mHost_Inquiries WHERE [File_Id] = '
    + LTRIM(STR(@FileId))      
SET @SQLStatement = @SQLStatement + '; DELETE FROM dbo.' + @TableName
    + ' WHERE [File_Id] = ' + LTRIM(STR(@FileId))      
SET @SQLStatement = @SQLStatement
    + '; DELETE FROM dbo.tPgt_FileRemarks WHERE [File_Id] = '
    + LTRIM(STR(@FileId))
SET @SQLStatement = @SQLStatement
    + '; DELETE FROM dbo.tPgt_FileProducts WHERE [File_Id] = '
    + LTRIM(STR(@FileId))
SET @SQLStatement = @SQLStatement
    + '; DELETE FROM dbo.tFile_FeeCalculated WHERE [File_Id] = '
    + LTRIM(STR(@FileId))
SET @SQLStatement = @SQLStatement
    + '; DELETE FROM dbo.tPgt_SubFeeDetails WHERE Sub_File_Id = '
    + LTRIM(STR(@SubFileId))
SET @SQLStatement = @SQLStatement
    + '; DELETE FROM dbo.tPgt_ReceivingFeeDetails WHERE Sub_File_Id = '
    + LTRIM(STR(@SubFileId))
SET @SQLStatement = @SQLStatement
    + '; DELETE FROM dbo.tPgt_SubFileDetails WHERE [File_Id] = '
    + LTRIM(STR(@FileId))      
SET @SQLStatement = @SQLStatement
    + '; DELETE FROM dbo.tFile_CustomerHeader WHERE [File_Id] = '
    + LTRIM(STR(@FileId))
SET @SQLStatement = @SQLStatement
    + '; DELETE FROM dbo.tPgt_FileDetails WHERE [File_Id] = '
    + LTRIM(STR(@FileId))
```

-- Build SQL Statement - Stop

Comment: What is the difference in query plans? Is there blocking? Why are you using dynamic SQL?

Comment: Problem solved. I try methods of batch delete with using while count and delete top(20000) and it only takes 1-2 minutes to finish the delete.